# am getting duplicate rows of data, how to solve this?

Tags: mysql, database

here's my sample sql code

```
SELECT * FROM wsrecruitcvhead AS CV, wsrecruittimes AS WT 
WHERE
CV.`ResumeTitle` LIKE '%search%'
OR ResumeSummaryIntroduction LIKE '%search%'
OR WT.`AvailableToWorkSunday` = 0 
OR WT.`AvailableToWorkMonday` = 0
OR WT.`AvailableToWorkTuesday` = 0 
OR WT.`AvailableToWorkWednesday` = 0 
OR WT.`AvailableToWorkThursday` = 0
OR WT.`AvailableToWorkFriday` = 0  
AND CV.`ResumeID` = WT.`ResumeID` 
ORDER BY CV.ResumeID ASC;
```

am getting duplicate rows of data...it didn't help when i tried `SELECT DISTINCT *` , what to do with this ?, how to solve it ?

Comment: You have mixed between OR and AND, you should enclosed parenthesis when applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
  FROM wsrecruitcvhead AS CV, wsrecruittimes AS WT
 WHERE CV.`ResumeTitle` LIKE '%search%'
    OR ResumeSummaryIntroduction LIKE '%search%'
    OR WT.`AvailableToWorkSunday` = 0
    OR WT.`AvailableToWorkMonday` = 0
    OR WT.`AvailableToWorkTuesday` = 0
    OR WT.`AvailableToWorkWednesday` = 0
    OR WT.`AvailableToWorkThursday` = 0
    OR (WT.`AvailableToWorkFriday` = 0
        AND CV.`ResumeID` = WT.`ResumeID`)
 ORDER BY CV.ResumeID ASC;
```

This means you don't have a good join between the two tables.  Learn to use the explicit join notation to save yourself this grief:

```
SELECT *
  FROM wsrecruitcvhead AS CV
  JOIN wsrecruittimes AS WT
    ON CV.`ResumeID` = WT.`ResumeID`
 WHERE CV.`ResumeTitle` LIKE '%search%'
    OR ResumeSummaryIntroduction LIKE '%search%'
    OR WT.`AvailableToWorkSunday` = 0
    OR WT.`AvailableToWorkMonday` = 0
    OR WT.`AvailableToWorkTuesday` = 0
    OR WT.`AvailableToWorkWednesday` = 0
    OR WT.`AvailableToWorkThursday` = 0
    OR WT.`AvailableToWorkFriday` = 0
 ORDER BY CV.ResumeID ASC;
```

However, although this is a simple and direct modification of your query, you probably had in mind:

```
SELECT *
  FROM wsrecruitcvhead AS CV
  JOIN wsrecruittimes AS WT
    ON CV.`ResumeID` = WT.`ResumeID`
 WHERE (CV.`ResumeTitle` LIKE '%search%'
        OR ResumeSummaryIntroduction LIKE '%search%'
       )
   AND (   WT.`AvailableToWorkSunday`    = 0
        OR WT.`AvailableToWorkMonday`    = 0
        OR WT.`AvailableToWorkTuesday`   = 0
        OR WT.`AvailableToWorkWednesday` = 0
        OR WT.`AvailableToWorkThursday`  = 0
        OR WT.`AvailableToWorkFriday`    = 0
       )
 ORDER BY CV.ResumeID ASC;
```

Or even (since there's no obvious reason to omit Saturday):

```
SELECT *
  FROM wsrecruitcvhead AS CV
  JOIN wsrecruittimes AS WT
    ON CV.`ResumeID` = WT.`ResumeID`
 WHERE (CV.`ResumeTitle` LIKE '%search%'
        OR ResumeSummaryIntroduction LIKE '%search%'
       )
   AND (   WT.`AvailableToWorkSunday`    = 0
        OR WT.`AvailableToWorkMonday`    = 0
        OR WT.`AvailableToWorkTuesday`   = 0
        OR WT.`AvailableToWorkWednesday` = 0
        OR WT.`AvailableToWorkThursday`  = 0
        OR WT.`AvailableToWorkFriday`    = 0
        OR WT.`AvailableToWorkSaturday`  = 0
       )
 ORDER BY CV.ResumeID ASC;
```

Comment: is it legal to replace the "AND" with "OR" instead?, since there's a parenthesis already that separates them ?

Comment: In the last two queries?  Yes, it's legal; it radically changes the query, though.  With the AND, then you are looking for a resume that matches the '%search%' bit and the person is not available to work on one day of the the week.  If you use OR instead of AND, then you're either looking for someone whose resume matches the search, or someone who can't work on one day of the week.  Actually, the day of the week part of the query is a bit suspect to my way of thinking - but you know what you are seeking better than me.

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` will only work if the rows are completely duplicate. Try a more selective `SELECT`, so instead of using `*`, select the actual columns you need.

Also have a look at `GROUP BY` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

This query is a little better than your and will make it easier to work with:

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM wsrecruitcvhead AS CV
INNER JOIN wsrecruittimes  AS WT ON (CV.`ResumeID` = WT.`ResumeID`) 
     WHERE (   CV.`ResumeTitle` LIKE '%search%'
            OR ResumeSummaryIntroduction LIKE '%search%'
            ) 
       AND (   WT.`AvailableToWorkSunday` = 0 
            OR WT.`AvailableToWorkMonday` = 0
            OR WT.`AvailableToWorkTuesday` = 0 
            OR WT.`AvailableToWorkWednesday` = 0 
            OR WT.`AvailableToWorkThursday` = 0
            OR WT.`AvailableToWorkFriday` = 0  
           )
  ORDER BY CV.ResumeID ASC;
```